# Adding MS CustomVision SDK to Xamarin PCL project fail

Tags: c#, xamarin, sdk, nuget-package

I'm tring to add the `Microsoft.Cognitive.CustomVision.Prediction v1.0.0` NuGet package to my Xamarin PCL project, but it throws me this error.

> Could not install package 'System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0'. You are trying
>   to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile49', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

Have anyone else managed to get this SDK up and running in an PCL (Portable Class Library)?

Comment: the custom vision libraries are not provided as PCLs.  See https://danatxamarin.com/2017/05/30/sample-custom-vision-in-xamarin-forms-with-azure-customvision-ai/

Comment: Thanks, I feared that. Will try the solution in your link then.